# "Each" vs "Every"

Tags: difference

I am preparing for the TOEIC exam, and I don't really understand the differences and similarities between "***Each***" and "***Every***". Can anyone answer my question? (I would also like an example)

Comment: Googling _each every_ brings up several websites which explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Each* vs *Every*  is a common issue even for some proficient writers, since they are really similar words. However, there are still some minor differences between them.

## 1. Separated or Generalised

Firstly, "**Each**" refers to an *individual object or person*, while **Every** refers to a group of objects or people lumped together as one. In a nutshell, **each** suggests separated (one by one), whereas **every** suggests generalized (all).

Let's look at an example:

> **Each**: Each child received a present.
> **Every**: Every child in the world deserves affection.

In the first sentence, **each** means every single one individually:

-> Child A received a present, Child B received a present, and so do Child C.

In the second sentence, **every** means whole in a group:

-> Child A B C all deserves affection.

## 2. How many objects?

The word **each** is used when there are only *two* objects in question.

For  example:

> Betty wore gloves on each hands -------------> **Correct**
> Betty wore gloves on every hands ------------> **Wrong**

---

**Each** and **Every** can be used interchangeably when refering to more than two objects.

For example:

> The bride received each item on her registry. -----------> **Correct**
> The bride received every item on her registry. ----------> **Correct**

Also note that **each** and **every** can be used alongside one another for emphasis.

For example:

> The bride received each and every item on her registry.

## Attribution

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/each-and-every/